# IIS Reverse Proxy not adding compression

Tags: iis, iis-8

I've spent the past few hours reading about problems people are having with reverse proxies in IIS, and I just can't seem to get my system to work.

I have added the registry variable, added dynamicCompressionBeforeCache to my web.config, but still when I make requests through the proxy IIS is not adding compression.

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:9555/" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Modules**
[image: IIS Module Configuration]

**Request**

`GET /kevin/0.txt HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.54902468.1481671910`

**Response**

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: ARR/3.0
Date: Sun, 05 Mar 2017 15:07:57 GMT
Content-Length: 2`

**Reverse Proxy server code**

```
const http = require("http");

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.write("hi");
    res.end();
}).listen(9555);
```

Comment: don't know much about reverse proxies, but surely as IIS is not handling the request, the reverse proxy server must be configured to handle the compression?